# AngularJS "then" sets up object but object is not accessible on Partial View

Tags: angularjs

Folks,

I have following Button Click which calls AngularJS $scope.getCustomerById method

```
<div><button type="button" ng-click="getCustomerById(cust.CustomerNumber);">detail of
{{cust.CustomerNumber}} customer</button>
</div>
```

Now my Controller JS code for getCustomerById is as below

```
$scope.getCustomerById = function (id) {        
CustomerService.getCustomer(id)
.then(function (data) {
$scope.customer = data.data; //which returns data correctly               
$location.path('Customer/' + $scope.customer.CustomerNumber.trim());                
}, function (error) {
alert(error);
});        
};
```

and it goes to Designated View as well, but this View Does not render **customer** data. My CustomerView is very simple,

```
<div data-ng-controller="CustomerController">
{{ customer.CustomerNumber }}//this doesn't show anything, eventhough $scope.customer     
                             //is set in controller as above
</div>
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: You should probably put your data into a service and use the service in both controllers.

Comment: As stated by AET above, you probably need to share the data between controllers. When you change the location, you're most likely going to a different view that has a different controller. So the first controller goes out of scope, and along with it the data you just got from the server ;)

Comment: AET and Sunil, I have one controller "CustomerController" having $scope.customers & $scope.customer variables. CustomerService has getCustomers & getCustomer(id) methods which work and get data successfully. On list.html I have defined ng-controller "CustomerController" and so in "customer.html". List.html shows all customers but customer.html does not show anything even if $scope.customer was assigned successfully. So I am confused as to what I am doing wrong in here. Help please folks.